# Finding the number of divisors?

Tags: c++

I wrote this code in order to find the number of the divisors of a given number. The method I am trying to implement finds all of the prime factors (which works) and takes number of similar prime numbers plus one (which gives the number of divisors).

e.g. 28 = 2*2 * 7 --> (2+1)*(1+1) = 6

This is my attempt:

```
int num = 20;
int next = 0;
int exponent = 0;
int numberOfDivisors = 1;

    start:
        for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++)
        {
            next = i;

            if (num%i == 0)
            {   
                if (i == next)
                {
                    exponent++; 
                }
                else
                {
                    numberOfDivisors *= (exponent+1);
                    exponent = 0;
                }

                if (num != i)
                {
                    num /= i;
                    goto start;
                }
            }
        }

    std::cout << numberOfDivisors << std::endl;
```

I just cannot figure out what I am missing.

Comment: `goto start`? Argh... it burns my eyes.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: geez, that goto was really spooky

Comment: I've read over the code time and time again, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Since I am a beginner programmer I was hoping someone more experienced could help me.

Comment: @AaronAAA if you are a beginner I would strongly recommend adding comments to explain what you are doing when. I suspect you will find any errors by doing this

Comment: When we ask what the question is, we expect you to describe what is wrong with the behaviour of your program (any error ? unexpected behaviour ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using goto is bad as you can see from the comments. After a little bit of clean up your code comes down to:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  int num = 20; 
  int numberOfDivisors = 1;

  for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++)
  {
    int exponent = 0;
    while (num % i == 0) {
        exponent++; 
        num /= i;
    }   
    numberOfDivisors *= (exponent+1);
  }

  std::cout << numberOfDivisors << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `goto` isn't helpful, actually, since you're already checked for lower prime factors there's no need to put `i` back to `2`.

```
    int numberOfDivisors = 1;
    int exponent = 1;
    int i = 2;
    while (i <= num) {
        if (num%i == 0) {   
            exponent++; 
            num /= i;
        }
        else {
            numberOfDivisors *= exponent;
            exponent = 1;
            i++;
        }
    }
    numberOfDivisors *= exponent; // <-- you were missing this, mainly
```

The actual problem with your code that wasn't style or performance related was that your loop finished with some `exponent` that you never included.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your code (and that `goto` interrupting the loop is just ugly), but one major problem with your code is that right after you enter the `for` loop, you set `next` to have the same value as `i`.

Then, you test something (namely, if `i` divides `num` evenly, but this doesn't matter) *and* (here is the critical part, you test if `i` is equal to `next`, which you *just* set them equal.

So, your code never has the opportunity to enter the `else` part of the corresponding `if`, which is where you would multiply the number of divisors by the `exponent + 1`.

As a result, your code always prints `1`, which is not what you wanted.

P.S.: That else may be entirely optimized out by the compiler as part of dead-code elimination, and this is what my gcc 4.7 actually does if I enable optimization `-O1` or higher.